# Console is a class in C# but works as an object?

Tags: c#, class, object

As far as I know, to access any function, method or member of a class, we need to use its corresponding object, but in C#, we generally use a class Console without any object to access its functions like:

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

So, what is the reason for this. I am pretty confused about the direct use of the Console class without any object. Please, if anybody can help, solve this dilemma for me.

Comment: See: "`static` methods": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members; as for "why does `Console` use `static` methods?": you only have one console/stdin/stdout/stderr

Answer (score -1):

`WriteLine` is a static method, static method belongs to the class rather than object of a class.

Comment: Thanks... now I got it.

Answer (score -2):

`WriteLine()` is `static` and can be called by it's classname `Console`.

In this example there is a `Method()` which has to be called on an instance of the class:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public static void StaticFunction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You can call me from my class-name");
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm called on an object.");
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)program..
{
    ExampleClass.StaticFunction();

    ExampleClass exampleObject = new ExampleClass();

    exampleObject.Method();
}
```

Comment: This is just a code dump with no explanation.

Comment: Sry. Hit the post to early ;-) But downvote within 2 seconds ?!?!